# Free body diagram and Newton's second law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> Two bodies of mass $m_1=50 \text{kg}$ and $m_2 = 10 \text{kg}$ are
>   connected with a light rope through a pulley (no friction between the
>   rope and the pulley). $m_2$ moves on surface with angle $37^{\circ}$
>   with a friction coefficient $\mu_k=0.5$. Force $\vec F$ acts on $m_1$.
>   The system was moving with a constant velocity for some time until the
>   force stopped and then the system started to accelerate. What's the
>   acceleration of the system?

[image: Free body diagram]

I assumed that the system accelerates to the left, therefore the equation for the $m_1$ would be:
$
\begin{cases}
 N_1=m_1 g\\ 
 T-N_1 \mu=m_1a
\end{cases}
$

Therefore $T=m_1(a+g \mu)$

For $m_2$ the equation would be:
$
\begin{cases}
 N_2=m_2 g \cos 37^{\circ}\\ 
 m_2 g \sin 37^{\circ} - T - N_2 \mu=m_2a
\end{cases}
$

Therefore $m_2 g \sin 37^{\circ} -T- m_2 g \cos 37^{\circ} \mu = m_2a $

The solution would be:

$100 \cdot 0.2024 - 50a -250=10a \\
a \approx -3.829 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}$

Which is wrong according to the answers. The answer should be $\approx -5.83\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}$ which you can get pretty close if instead of $10a$ in the last step it was $-10a$. So I'm pretty sure that my mistake here is with the signs (of the acceleration), but I can't figure out why I'm wrong.

Comment: Could you take the numbers out and replace them with variables (or at least numbers with units)? It's really hard to follow what you're doing when all I see are numbers with no way of determining their significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** The problem says that the system was moving right with constant velocity. So, all the friction forces will work towards left.

Hence, the equations will become
$$T+N_1 \mu = m_1 a$$

and

$$m_2 g \sin 37°- T + m_2 g \cos 37° = m_2a$$

Solving these will give you the right answer!

Elementary, my dear Watson!